# producer send message at the rate of 1gbps and consumer consume at the rate of 250mbps , So how many consumer we need for smooth transaction?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, producer-consumer

producer send message at the rate of 1gbps and consumer consume at the rate of 250mbps , So how many consumer we need for smooth transaction in Kafka ?

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly done by partitioning your topic into partitions creating an equivalent number of consumers so that kafka can assign each consumer to one partition.
The question now is how many partitions you need. This is best answered in the lab with load tests.
Please note that writing/producing messages usually faster than consuming them so in your case you need at least 4 partitions